# UEFI Windows cannot boot - bootlog comparison

Tags: linux, windows, boot, partitioning, clone

I had a linux+windows dual boot system with shared UEFI partition. My disk looked like this

```
Device             Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme1n1p1      2048     534527    532480   260M EFI System
/dev/nvme1n1p2    534528     567295     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme1n1p3    567296  588566527 587999232 280.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme1n1p4 998166528 1000214527   2048000  1000M Windows recovery environmen
/dev/nvme1n1p5 588566528  589615103   1048576   512M Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme1n1p6 589615104  998166527 408551424 194.8G Linux filesystem
```

I bought a new hard drive and decided to clone the Windows system partition to the new one using clonezilla partition-to-partition cloning. My new disk looks like this

```
Device         Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    34      32767      32734    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p2 32768 1953523711 1953490944 931.5G Microsoft basic data
```

Now I wanted to fix the uefi boot partition so I did

```
Diskpart
> list volume
> select volume 2 // select EFI partition
> assign letter=Z 
bcdboot C:\WINDOWS /l pl-pl /s Z: /f UEFI // C: is the new larger partition
bcdedit /set {default} bootlog Yes
```

When I try to boot it I get a black screen with mouse cursor. The bootlog looks like this: https://pastebin.com/CmAvqE93

On the other hand the healthy bootlog of my old system looks like this: https://pastebin.com/LPY06dbn

I'd like to ask do you see anything in the bad bootlog that'd indicate why it's not working ?

Comment: In UEFI mode, and for this specific scenario, you always need to clone the ESP (EFI System Partition) as well.

Comment: so it's impossible to have a ESP on a different drive than windows system partition ? I'd prefer not to have two different ESPs but one shared between windows and linux

Comment: Yes, sure you can and should have only one and where the system partition(s) reside is irrelevant. That said, because the intended Windows system partition is now a different one, you may need to reinstall the Windows bootloader manager.

Comment: so using `bcdboot` should not fix the issue ? I thought that by using it I set the ESP to boot windows from the new partition

Comment: I don't know about that. Typically I only deal with Linux and in the rare cases I had to move a dual-boot to a new drive I've cloned everything and then removed the old drive. Also at one time the Windows partitions was in different drive that was kept and the dual-boot just worked with the new drive clone (ESP+Linux).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it. Basically the problem was with using clonezilla to copy the old windows partition to the new partition; when I used the macrium reflect to copy the partition and did the rest the same as before it worked.
Thanks for help !

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.